# Vaadin redirecting to a URL from button click

Tags: java, vaadin

I have searched for a long time, but I really cannot figure this out.

How do I redirect the user to a new external link (e.g. *www.google.com*) when they click a button in Vaadin?

The only thing I have managed to do so far is to put the link into a link

```
Link link = new Link("link", new ExternalResource("http://www.google.com"));
```

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
getUI().getPage().setLocation("http://www.google.com");
```

References: [Page (Vaadin 7.2.1 API)](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#setLocation%28java.lang.String%29) and [Vaadin application lifecycle (Book of Vaadin)](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.lifecycle.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! Is it possible for you to tell me how to open the page in a new tab? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3702643 No worries. I think that you may want to start with a fresh question with that. Post back here and I'll answer it.

Comment: @user3702643 Please post the new question link

Comment: @user2410148 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039476/vaadin-open-link-in-new-tab/24039630#24039630

Comment: I am also facing the redirect issue. If i use this way as you mentioned above. the page is redirecting into internal page not the main page. Could you please help me?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the latest (.18) version. Does somebody know how is it achieved in more recents versions?