# Vaadin open link in new tab

Tags: java, vaadin

I have the following piece of code that I wrote using Vaadin. The code opens the page `www.google.com` when the user clicks the button.

My question is is there any way for me to specify that the page is to be opened in a new tab?

Thanks.

```
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        getUI().getPage().setLocation("http://www.google.com");
    }
});
```

Comment: Similar Question: [*Generate an HTML page, and open in a new window, from a Vaadin 8 app*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51691041/642706)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
getUI().getPage().open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
```

The `_blank` window name is important here. Beware that you may also have browsers that <strike>will</strike> might open the resource in a new window instead.

There is also another signature to the `open()` method, i.e.

```
open(String url, String windowName, boolean tryToOpenAsPopup)
```

that may fit the bill. HTH.

References: [Page (Vaadin 7.2.1 API)](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#setLocation%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: NP, but remember that the `_blank` window name is subjecting the behavior to the browsers. I suppose that's why Vaadin offers the second method signature. I tested o`_blank` on Firefox & Chrome but I can't tell about any other. HTH.

Comment: Did you get it to open in a new tab ?

Comment: @Don No , I can't . It just open in new browser window not with newtab.

Comment: @Cataclysm , yah that's the thing; at last we ended up showing links as basic html links so that user can choose to open in a new tab as usual.

Comment: I have the same problem. This opens a link in a new page, not in a new tab.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(new ExternalResource(url));
opener.setFeatures("");
opener.extend(button);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Button`, `BrowserWindowOpener` and `getUI().getPage().open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");` is discouraged since that is usually blocked by popup blockers.

Instead go with the `Link` component:

```
final Link link = new Link("Google", new ExternalResource("http://www.google.com"));
link.setTargetName("_blank");
```

See more in the [Vaadin Link Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-link.html)

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers work for me on Vaadin 24, lots of deprecated methods.
This currenly works:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().open("https://stackoverflow.com","_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

**Solution 1**

If you want your button to open a new tab, the BrowserWindowOpener might be the right solution.

```
Button viewBtn = new Button("Click me");
BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(new ExternalResource("http://www.example.com"));
opener.setWindowName("_blank");
opener.extend(viewBtn);
```

**Solution 2**

Your button should open in a new tab only when Ctrl (Alt, Shift, ...) key on the keyboard is hold. If not, open in existing tab.
In this case you can try to open a new tab using Page#open() method. Be aware that browsers will probably try to block your action and will warn user that they have blocked a pop-up window (even though it is not a pop-up but a new tab).

```
Button viewBtn = new Button("Click me", VaadinIcons.EYE);
viewBtn.addClickListener(ev -> {
  if (ev.isCtrlKey()) {
      Page.getCurrent().open("http://www.example.com", "_blank", false);
  } else {
      Page.getCurrent().setLocation("http://www.example.com");
  }
});
```

**Solution 3**

If you want the common behavior when the left click opens in existing tab and the middle mouse button click in a new tab, use the link instead of the button. In this case browsers probably let you open a new tab.

```
Link link = new Link(null, new ExternalResource(UriUtil.createAdUri(ad)));
link.setIcon(VaadinIcons.EYE);
```