# Open link in a new window using MenuBar.Command

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a MenuBar in my VAADIN application, in this MenuBar i have a link to my wiki:

```
Wiki = new Link();
        Wiki.setCaption("Wiki");
        Wiki.setStyleName("mypicto");
        Wiki.setImmediate(true);
        Wiki.setSizeUndefined();
        Wiki.setIcon(iconWiki);
```

With a Command:

```
MenuBar.Command wikiLink = new MenuBar.Command() {

            public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                getUI().getPage().open("url_to_wiki","_blank");
            }
        };
```

then i add the link and the commmand in my MenuBar

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

menuBar.addItem("Wiki",iconWiki, wikiLink);
```

The problem is, i can't open the link in a new tab, it's only opening in a pop-up, wich is blocked by default in almost all web browsers.

Is there a way to open my link in another tab instead of Pop-up in my MenuBar?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039476/vaadin-open-link-in-new-tab

Comment: If you figure it out, let me know, I had this issue yesterday!

Comment: getUI().getPage().open("url_to_wiki","_blank",false);
Doesn't work better (saw it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039476/vaadin-open-link-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for... https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/activelink

This addon let me open a page in a new tab. I tested it out using this code from the Vaadin 7 Cookbook.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DemoActiveLink extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DemoActiveLink.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    ActiveLink link = new ActiveLink("Vaadin", new ExternalResource(
            "http://vaadin.com"));
    link.setTargetName("_blank");
    link.addListener(new LinkActivatedListener() {
        public void linkActivated(LinkActivatedEvent event) {
            Notification.show("Link was opened in a new window.");
        }
    });

    setContent(link);
  }
}
```

&

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DemoButtonLink extends UI {

@Override
public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Button button = new Button("Vaadin");
    button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            getPage().open("http://vaadin.com", "Vaadin");
        }
    });
    button.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);
    setContent(button);
}

}
```

Comment: You may or may not need:

   " @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DemoActiveLink.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    } "

This works for my setup.

Comment: I thought it was the solution, but no, i need this to be in a menubar.Command, not in a button or an activeLink