# Vaadin 23 open new browser tab with url on Button click

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I may open a browser new tab with Anchor component configured with `target=_blank`. How to do the same in Vaadin23 with the `Button` component inside the `ClickListener` code?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Could you use a link styled as a button?

Comment: yeah.. I love Vaadin because I don't need to deeply dive into the css :) I have a number of small buttons already, and would like to add another one for `permlink` url. Is there a simple way to style Anchor like the Button with `ButtonVariant.LUMO_SMALL, ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no built in styling right now. I thought we had, but it might have been in an earlier version. You can follow the discussion here https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/1803

Comment: The same should still apply https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039630

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `UI.getCurrent().getPage().open(String url)`, which opens the URL in a new tab by default.

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me", e -> {
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().open("https://stackoverflow.com");
});
add(button);
```

Comment: You can also add a second argument to the open() method, which specifies in which window to open it. (_blank is probably default)

Comment: Yes, _blank is the default. You can also specify for example _self to open the page in the same browser tab: https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.8.15/com/vaadin/flow/component/page/Page.html#open-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-